# Sitecore Redis Timeout Exception on ZADD Shared_ExpirationIndex

Tags: sitecore-client, solr, xconnect, azure, redis

We are using Sitecore 9.3 in our multi-site application. And we are using Redis Cache in one of our application. We are suddenly facing the below exception in our Redis server. Please find the below exception details:

```
Exception: StackExchange.Redis.RedisTimeoutException
Message: Timeout performing ZADD shared_ExpirationIndex (5000ms), inst: 9, qs: 6, in: 0, serverEndpoint: Unspecified/XXX.redis.cache.windows.net:6390, mgr: 10 of 10 available, clientName: XXX, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=8,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=21,Free=32746,Min=8,Max=32767), v: 2.0.519.65453 (Please take a look at this article for some common client-side issues that can cause timeouts: https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Timeouts)
Source: StackExchange.Redis
```

Below is the code used to set the redis cache value:

```
            var cache = Connection.GetDatabase();
            var serializedModel = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
            var cachedValue = expirationInMinutes != 0 
                ? cache.StringSet(cacheKeyName, serializedModel, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(expirationInMinutes))
                : cache.StringSet(cacheKeyName, serializedModel);
```

Please suggest the reason for this timeout exception.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced a similer type of issue, could you please check the following:

- In the `Web.config` and `Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.config` files, increase the pollingInterval attribute value on both Private and Shared session state provider definitions from 2 to 60 seconds.
- In the `Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.config file`, find the `timeoutBetweenLockAttempts parameter`. Increase its value from 10 to 200 milliseconds.

Review your config files from your CD server according to Sitecore recommendation in this KB article here https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0858026

I also recommend you check if the cache tuning is enough or not.

- [Cache Tunning in Sitecore](https://himmatsinghdulawat.blogspot.com/2022/09/cache-tunning-in-sitecore.html)
- [Monitor and Tune the Cache on the CD Server](https://himmatsinghdulawat.blogspot.com/2023/04/monitor-and-tune-cache-on-cd-server.html)
- [IsLanguageFallbackValid Field Cache Tunning in Sitecore](https://himmatsinghdulawat.blogspot.com/2023/09/islanguagefallbackvalid-field-cache-tunning-in-sitecore.html)

If your problem still persists then (ensure that you are not customizing the Redis):

- Ensure CPU usage is not high. This is a limitation from `StackExchange.Redis`.
- Increase operationTimeoutInMilliseconds from 5000 ms to higher. https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0464570
- Scale your Redis

See the Blog Post for more details: [Intermittent StackExchange.Redis.RedisTimeout Exception in Sitecore](https://himmatsinghdulawat.blogspot.com/2023/10/intermittent-stackexchange-redis-redistimeout-exception-in-sitecore.html)

Comment: We are using Inproc for Session and also the above recommended settings are already in place. 
FYI,We are using the below settings for tracking redis shared session:
 <add name="redis" type=" Sitecore.SessionProvider.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider, Sitecore.SessionProvider.Redis" connectionString="session" pollingInterval="60" applicationName="shared" operationTimeoutInMilliseconds="5000" retryTimeoutInMilliseconds="16000" connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds="3000" pollingMaxExpiredSessionsPerSecond="20" />
Can you suggest the value for operationTimeoutInMilliseconds?

Comment: The final values must be tuned per-solution as a result of load testing. Tune operationTimeoutInMilliseconds 15000, connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds 5000.

Can I ask do you have a custom Redis Code?
Which environment you are using PaaS or IaaS?

As per your question and code, I guess you are customizing Redis. Am I right?